# how to convert MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use Sequelize to run my MySQL statements for deleting a record, making a temp table to throw  the left over data into then truncating the original table, then throw the records temp table back to the original table and drop the temp table... how do I do this in sequelize, here is my code...

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../../../models');

router.post('/:userId', (req, res) => {
db.reading.distroy({
where: {
  userId: req.params.userId,
  order: [id],
  limit: 1
}
})

const sql = `DELETE FROM readings WHERE user_id=${req.params.user_id}\
 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;\
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpreadings(
  user_id int not null,
  date text not null,
  sugarB int not null,
  carbsB int not null,
  insulinB int not null,
  insulinSB int not null,
  insulinFB int not null,
  sugarL int not null,
  carbsL int not null,
  insulinL int not null,
  hbp int not null,
  lbp int not null,
  hr int not null,
  sugarD int not null,
  carbsD int not null,
  insulinD int not null);\
  INSERT INTO tmpreadings(user_id,date,sugarB,carbsB,insulinB,insulinSB,\
    insulinFB,sugarL,carbsL,insulinL,hbp,lbp,hr,sugarD,carbsD,insulinD)\
    SELECT user_id,date,sugarB,carbsB,insulinB,insulinSB,\
    insulinFB,sugarL,carbsL,insulinL,hbp,lbp,hr,sugarD,carbsD,insulinD 
    FROM readings;\
  DROP TABLE readings;\
CREATE TABLE readings(
  id int not null auto_increment,
  user_id int not null,
  date text not null,
  sugarB int not null,
  carbsB int not null,
  insulinB int not null,
  insulinSB int not null,
  insulinFB int not null,
  sugarL int not null,
  carbsL int not null,
  insulinL int not null,
  hbp int not null,
  lbp int not null,
  hr int not null,
  sugarD int not null,
  carbsD int not null,
  insulinD int not null,
  primary key (id),
  foreign key(user_id) references users(id));\
INSERT INTO readings(user_id,date,sugarB,carbsB,insulinB,insulinSB,\
  insulinFB,sugarL,carbsL,insulinL,hbp,lbp,hr,sugarD,carbsD,insulinD)\
  SELECT user_id,date,sugarB,carbsB,insulinB,insulinSB,insulinFB,\
  sugarL,carbsL,insulinL,hbp,lbp,hr,sugarD,carbsD,insulinD\
  FROM tmpreadings;\
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmpreadings`;

connection.query(sql, (err, results, rows) => {
if (err) {
  return res.send(err.message);
} else {
  res.send('Successfully Deleted Row');
}
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

I've tried to start the conversion with db.reading.destroy
but got stuck.. can anyone help me

I've looked at the docs and I came up with this can anyone tell me if this is right?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');

router.post('/:userId', (req, res) => {
await sequelize.query(
`DELETE FROM readings WHERE userId= :userId\
 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;\
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpreadings(
  date text not null,
  sugarB int not null,
  carbsB int not null,
  insulinB int not null,
  insulinSB int not null,
  insulinFB int not null,
  sugarL int not null,
  carbsL int not null,
  insulinL int not null,
  hbp int not null,
  lbp int not null,
  hr int not null,
  sugarD int not null,
  carbsD int not null,
  insulinD int not null,
  userId int not null);\
  INSERT INTO tmpreadings(date,sugarB,carbsB,insulinB,insulinSB,insulinFB,\
    sugarL,carbsL,insulinL,hbp,lbp,hr,sugarD,carbsD,insulinD,userId)\
    SELECT date,sugarB,carbsB,insulinB,insulinSB,insulinFB,sugarL,\
    carbsL,insulinL,hbp,lbp,hr,sugarD,carbsD,insulinD,userId 
    FROM readings;\
  TRUNCATE TABLE readings;\
INSERT INTO readings(date,sugarB,carbsB,insulinB,insulinSB,insulinFB,\
  sugarL,carbsL,insulinL,hbp,lbp,hr,sugarD,carbsD,insulinD,userId)\
  SELECT date,sugarB,carbsB,insulinB,insulinSB,insulinFB,sugarL,/
  carbsL,insulinL,hbp,lbp,hr,sugarD,carbsD,insulinD,userId\
  FROM tmpreadings;\
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmpreadings`,
{
  replacements: { userId: [req.params.userId] },
  type: QueryTypes.DELETE
}
);
})
```

Comment: You should have an array of query statements, not one big query full of multiple statements.

Comment: Additionally, `${req.params.user_id}` is a SQL injection bug. You should be using prepared statements with placeholder values, something very easy to do in Sequelize.

Comment: I'm new to sequelize... can you show me how to that... I'm just trying to convert  so I can get rid of that BIG sequel statement

Comment: It's all right there in the [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html) under "Replacements".

Comment: does this look right I looked at the docs and this is what i came up with